# Vuetify.js: set CSS class on mouse hover event using v-hover component

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the class to apply on a Vuetify.js component based on whether there is a mouse hover or not:

```
<v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    width="344"
  >
    <v-hover>
    <v-card-title
      slot-scope="hover"
      :class="`${hover? class1: class2}`">
      <div>
        <span class="headline">Hover</span>              
        </div>
      </div>

    </v-card-title>
    </v-hover>
  </v-card>
```

The CSS classes simply set the `background-color` property:

```
.class1 {
  background-color:red;
}

.class2 {
  background-color:blue;
}
```

For some reason, this is not working. What am I missing?

[**Codepen.**](https://codepen.io/begueradj/pen/mQEybj)

Comment: Did you see the error in the console?

Comment: I was trying to provide an MCVE , but you are right, thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You miss **quotes** in your prop `class` binding and **curly braces** in your `slot-scope` prop.

It should be defined like this :

```
slot-scope="{ hover }"
:class="`${hover? 'class1': 'class2'}`">
```

---

[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WYxbmx?editors=1111)

[Vuetify Hover Doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/hover)